# Need clarification on recursive functions.

Tags: logic, computability, recursion

Given any function $f: \mathbb{N}_0 \rightarrow \mathbb{N}_0$ and a recursive $h:\mathbb{N}_0 \rightarrow \mathbb{N}_0$ , I know that to prove $h\circ f$ is recursive I only need to prove that $f$ is recursive.

What if I define $$ f(n) =
\begin{cases}
h(f(i)),  & \text{if there exists $i<n$ s.t. $P(i)$} \\
1, & \text{otherwise},
\end{cases}$$
for some recursive predicate P? Is $f$ recursive?

I think $f$ is recursive, and here's my reasoning:

I can rewrite the condition "if there exists unique $i<n$ s.t. $P(i)$" into a predicate $Q$,and so $Q$ is recursive. "Otherwise" in this case would be $\lnot Q$, which is also recursive. I can now write $f = h(f(i))\cdot \mathbb{1}_Q + 1\cdot \mathbb{1}_{\lnot Q}  $ and so $f$ is recursive.

Am I right? I'm not sure how to handle $f(i)$ in the argument of $h$, but I think that since previous computations of $f(n)$ would have produced a sequence of numbers, I should treat $f(i)$ as a constant instead of as an unknown function.

Any insight is much appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: What is your question?  Are you trying to prove something?  Are you asking if a proof is correct?  If so, what is it you are trying to prove?

Comment: I wondering if $f$ defined above is recursive, and if my reasoning is correct. I'm going to edit in the make my intentions clearer thanks!

Comment: Your $f$ is not even well defined -- for example if $P(i)$ is always true and $h$ is the successor function, then $f(0)=1$ and $f(1)=2$, but it's not well specified whether you want $f(2)$ to be $2$ or $3$ (since $0$ and $1$ are both possible $i$s in this case).

Comment: I see. Thanks for pointing that out. My concern is actually only with $f(i)$ being an argument of a known recursive function. I didn't think through when creating this example.